# Vue show menu function

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a function that shows my menu but when I click it, I only get errors.

`app.js`:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

In my component, I have:

```
<div class="relative inline-block text-left unselectable" id="demo">   <!-- Menu -->
        <button type="button" v-on:click="show = !show" class="menu-btn material-icons">more_vert</button>
            <div class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" v-if="show">
                <div class="dropdown-list rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                    <ul>
                      <li class="block py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-sm"><button class="list-btn">Perfil</button></li>
                      <li class="block py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-sm"><button class="list-btn">Definições</button></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="block py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-sm"><button class="list-btn sair" @click.prevent="logout">Sair</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                
            </div>        
      </div>
```

I get these errors:

> Property or method "show" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> found in
>
> at resources/js/components/Utils/UserMenu.vue

and

> app.js:39733 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #example

PS: I just started in vue.js, do I need to export or declare something?

Comment: You have at least three apps as you're trying to mount `#app`, `#demo`, and `#example`.  You should have only one.  The rest should be components.  Probably it would help to study the component [guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Composing-with-Components) basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

You have to declare show prop in data so it can be used in template otherwise you'll get error that property is not defined

App.vue

```
<template>
 <div class="relative inline-block text-left unselectable" id="demo">   <!-- Menu -->
    <button type="button" v-on:click="show = !show" class="menu-btn material-icons">more_vert</button>
        <div class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" v-if="show">
            <div class="dropdown-list rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                <ul>
                  <li class="block py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-sm"><button class="list-btn">Perfil</button></li>
                  <li class="block py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-sm"><button class="list-btn">Definições</button></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="block py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-sm"><button class="list-btn sair" @click.prevent="logout">Sair</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>                
      </div>        
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data(){
    return {
      show :false
    }
  },
}
</script>
```